# MySQL why this happends ob json insert? "{\"host\": \"c\"}"

Tags: mysql, json

Whats the deal with mysql and json?  It makes no sense.

1) This is how I insert data for first insert into a record

```
truncate git_object;
INSERT INTO git_object (user_id,git_meta) VALUES ('11111','[{"host": "a", "id": "1"}]');
```

Here is the result:

```
11111, [{"id": "1", "host": "a"}]
```

Now I want to append into the array:

```
Update git_object
set  git_meta=JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(git_meta, '$', '{"host": "c"}')
where user_id='11111';
```

Here are the results:

```
11111, [{"id": "1", "host": "a"}, "{\"host\": \"c\"}"]
```

So..what is the deal with the "\" in the last insert?

This wrecks havoc from calling mysql from python because the first element when I decode as json will return a python hash while the other is a string.

Why does this happen?

Comment: This is why because **JSON**  data format is like this {"**var_1**":"**value**","**var_2**":"**value**"}. So JSON needs to distinguish the double quotes included in the input with those double quotes that are used to format the JSON hence it adds **\"** slash to those double quotes that are appended in a input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append) does not attempt to parse as JSON the values it receives as arguments.

```
SET git_meta = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(git_meta, '$', '{"host": "c"}')
```

You pass it a string as its third argument, it appends a string to the array stored in the `git_meta` column. This is why the quotes are escaped.

There are two simple ways to achieve your goal:

1. wrap the object you want to append into an array and use [`JSON_MERGE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge) to combine the JSON documents:

   ```
   SET git_meta = JSON_MERGE(git_meta, '[{"host": "c"}]')
   ```
2. use function [`JSON_OBJECT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) to create a JSON document that contains the object you need and pass this object to `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()` as the value to put in the JSON column:

   ```
   SET git_meta = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(git_meta, '$', JSON_OBJECT('host', 'c'))
   ```

Comment: Thanks!  it appears that cast('{}' as json) works too

Comment: Indeed, that's also an option. I am not a fan of [`cast`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html), many times its usage shows a flaw in the database design, but in this case it is not a flaw. It is just an alternative of the `JSON_OBJECT()` when you have the object already represented as JSON (from an external source, for example).